# Aggregation by $group got a strange behavirous with $first

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, aggregation

I've got a strange behavior with an aggregation. I've got lots of document like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "xxxxxxx",
    "someId" : "xxxxxxx",
    "creationDatetime" : ISODate("2019-07-11T15:10:35.747Z"),
    "versions" : [ 
        {
            "versionDatetime" : ISODate("2019-07-11T15:10:35.785Z"),
            "startDatetime" : ISODate("2019-03-29T09:07:04.000Z"),
            "endDatetime" : ISODate("2019-08-05T11:07:04.000Z"),
            "name" : "ThisIsAName"
        },
        {
            "versionDatetime" : ISODate("2019-07-11T15:20:35.785Z"),
            "startDatetime" : ISODate("2019-03-29T09:07:04.000Z"),
            "endDatetime" : ISODate("2019-08-05T11:07:04.000Z"),
            "name" : "ThisIsAName"
        }
    ],
    "_class" : "com.xx.xx.xx.MyDocument"
}
```

I try to aggregate each document by "someId" and "versions.name" when there is a new version.

```java
private List<> function(List<String> someIds) {
Instant now = Instant.now();

        MatchOperation matchOperation = Aggregation.match(new Criteria(MyDocument.version.dateTime)
                .gte(now.minus(1, ChronoUnit.MINUTES).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES))
                .lt(now.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES))
                .and(MyDocument.id).in(someIds));

        SortOperation sortByUpdateDatetime = sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, MyDocument.version.dateTime);

        GroupOperation groupByService = group(MyDocument.someId, MyDocument.version.name)
                .count().as(count)
                .first(MyDocument.someId).as(someId)
                .first(MyDocument.version.name).as(name)
                .first(MyDocument.version.dateTime).as(lastUpdate);

        Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(matchOperation, sortByUpdateDatetime, groupByService);
        AggregationResults<ClientAggregationResult> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(
                aggregation, MyDocument.class, ClientAggregationResult.class);

        return result.getMappedResults().stream().map(this::toDataDTO).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

In mongoShell it looks like this:

```
db.getCollection('parkingRight').aggregate([ { 
    "$match" : { 
        "versions.datetime" : { 
            "$gte" : { 
                "$date" : "2020-06-23T15:00:00.000Z"} , 
                "$lt" : { "$date" : "2020-06-24T17:20:00.000Z"}} , 
                "someId" : { "$in" : [ "xxx", "yyy", "kkk"]}}} , 
                { "$sort" : { "versions.datetime" : -1}} , 
                { "$group" : { 
                    "_id" : { 
                        "someId" : "$someId" , 
                        "name" : "$versions.name"} , 
                    "count" : {"$sum" : 1} , 
                    "someId" : { "$first" : "$someId"} , 
                    "name" : { "$first" : "$versions.name"} , 
                    "lastDate" : { "$first" : "$versions.datetime"}
                }
            }
        ])
```

But when there is multiple versions the aggragated Doc concatenate the field name like this: `name: ThisIsAName,ThisIsAName`. there is a ThisIsAName for each number of version of the doc.

the others fields are normal.

Do you know if this is an error from my aggragation or a strange behaviour ?

Comment: Can you add a document and mongo query also rather than java code.

Comment: I added the mongoShell query for more clarity

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behavior.

In the aggregation, the match stage selects entire documents, not portions of them, so after this stage the document in the pipeline looks exactly like the original document.

The sort stage also operations on whole documents, and will not reorder the elements in the embedded array.  After this stage the documents may be in a different order than before, but each document will still be in exactly the same form it was at the start.

When the group stage begins, each documents in the pipeline has been passed through completely unmodified.  Since `versions` is an array of documents, projecting `versions.name` will give you an array containing the value of the `name` field from each document.

If you want to deal with individual version documents, you might unwind the versions array after the initial match stage to consider all versions, or use project/addFields with one of the array operators to eliminate the entries you are not interested in.

Comment: You are certainly right but why version.datetime do not have the same behaviour ? the field lastDate is filled with only the first match.

Comment: Because you used `$first` with datetime. But not with name. That's the reason for the behavior.

Comment: @afourcad When I tested this, I got back arrays for both name and dateTime, even if there was only value.